# fraction rased to a power of log base 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, fractions

The below expression simplifies to $\frac{y}{n}$,
$$
\left(\dfrac{1}{2} \right)^{\log_2\left(\frac{1}{y/n}\right)}
$$

I have tried to change bases but haven't figured out how to come up with the solution $y/n$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the power apply to the whole fraction or only to the numerator?

Comment: You may use : $B^{log_B (A)} = A$

Comment: If I raise B to the power of B that " gives" A , I get A ( by definition).

Comment: There is something missing from the equation-as it is, you end up with $y/n = y/n$ which has no solution.

Comment: I have added the parenthesis. Wolfram gives the answer y/n: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%29%5E%28log2%281%2F%28y%2Fn%29%29%29

Answer (score 0):

let $y/n = x$
$$(2^{-1})^{\log_2 x^{-1}} =2^{\log_2 x}=x=\frac{y}{n}$$

Comment: errors?
Wolfram gives y/n: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%29%5E%28log2%281%2F%28y%2Fn%29%29%29

Comment: your solution by rewriting 1/2 to 2^-1 helped. It makes sense now. Thanks.